# How to list the virtual machines running on my macOS?

Tags: macos, vmware

I use minikube running a local K8s cluster in my macOS, it will running a virtual machine on my macOS, I have a question about it.

how to list the virtual machines running on my macOS?
and how to login the vm.

Comment: In **Terminal**, assuming your `PATH` contains e.g. `/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Library/Apple/usr/bin` then `vmrun list` will _list_ all running **VMware Fusion** _virtual machines_.